# This.collection has data but not this.collection.models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

So i have a collection already fetched and passed it to a View...

```
var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        console.log(this.collection); // Here shows me data...
        console.log(this.collection.models);// But here shows me []?????????
        this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);
        this.categorias();
    },

    categorias: function(){
        this.cats = [];
        this.collection.each(function(model)
                            {
                                console.log(model.get('familia'));
                                //this.cats.push(model.get('familia'));
                            });
        //return _.uniq(this.categorias,false);
    },

    render: function(){
        var cat = _.uniq(this.cats, false);
        this.$el.html(Handlebars.templates.products(cat));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Let me put the Router:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "" : "productos",
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.productoItems = new Productos();
        this.productoItems.fetch({reset:true});

        //this.productoItem = new Producto();
        //Crear la vista del detalle de un producto     

        this.productosView = new ProductsView({collection: this.productoItems});
    },

    productos: function(){
        $('#app').html(this.productosView.render().el);
    }

});

/*********************************/
var app = new AppRouter();

$(function(){
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Please ignore the comments... in the categorias function when i `console.log(this.collections)` it returns the collection obviously duh! but when i `console.log(this.collections.models)` returns me an empty [] so the .each doesnt work properly...
Any suggestions?? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your collection has any model loaded?

Comment: As @ejosafat commented, you're simply not taking into account asynchronism. You'll simply see the data when using `console.log(this.collection);` because the data will be loaded by the time you expand the object in your console.

Comment: @ejosafat I edited so the collection has already a model by the time im passing to the view... and Loamhoof, but why this.collection.models is not showing anything??? if you say that by the time the data already loaded its supposed that this.collections and this.collection.models shows data as well...

Comment: try to `console.log(this.collection.length)` to see if your fetch has completed by the time you're logging `this.collection`

Comment: this is what i got when console.log(this.collection) it says length:0, but it contains models...so what??? i know its something basic... but i cant find to work...

r {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
_byId: Object
_events: Object
_listenerId: "l2"
length: 11
models: Array[11]
__proto__: s